# discreetly listen on nflog groups using tcpdump

Tags: tcpdump

I just discovered the tcpdump feature which allows you to listen to an nflog groups, (i.e. tcpdump -i nflog:1337). It does however seem to also break any application which relies on reading from this group. Is there any way to do this without breaking these applications?